# CSS style applied to jQuery tool tip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tooltip attached to a checkbox. Here is the jQuery that controls it:

```
  $("#theform :input").tooltip({
  position: "center right",
  offset: [-2, 10],
  effect: "fade",
  opacity: 0.7
  });
```

Here is the CSS to control its appearance:

```
.tooltip {
  background-color:#000;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  padding:10px 15px;
  width:200px;
  display:none;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:left;
  font-size:12px;

 //For Firefox 
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
}
```

And here is the code for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="End" id="End" value=1 title = "Tooltip text here" />
```

The style is not in its own sheet. It's part of the file where the jQuery code resides, wrapped in style tags. The tooltip itself is working; the CSS is not. I can't figure out why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [overriding css jquery tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780759/overriding-css-jquery-tooltip)

Comment: Are you sure the CSS class of the tooltip is in fact `.tooltip`?  Do you have a jsfiddle or anything you can share?