# Tooltip in google maps infowindo and twitter bootstrap tooltip isn't appearing the same

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

[image: tool tip]
<- This is how the tool tip usually looks when using Twitter Bootstrap. I'm trying to have a tooltip in a google map's info window. However, the tool tip that appears is different from the above picture, despite them being on the same page. This is how it looks:
[image: info window]

I've inspected the html and it seems that the css that the google maps infowindow is using is overriding the bootstrap css. I've tried to override the css (following this: [Overriding CSS styles of the jQuery UI Tooltip widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780759/overriding-css-jquery-tooltip)) but the tooltip in the info window doesn't change. Is there other way to get the tooltip in the infowindow to look like the first picture?

Comment: You should trigger bootstrap tooltip initialization after infowindow's content set. Try calling `domready` event for infowindows and inside, call `tooltip()` for the id of your content.

Answer (score 2):

I added:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
    $("#helpPop").tooltip({
        placement : 'right'                     
    });
```

and now it displays correctly

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed.