# How can I mimic Leaflet.Draw tooltip style with a different tooltip plugin?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, tooltip, leaflet.draw

I'm trying to implement leaflet.draw-like behaviour on a map that also uses leaflet.draw (using Draw to drop markers, but then custom js to draw in routes). I would therefore like helpful tooltips on this custom drawing function to look like the draw tooltips.

How can I do so? I'm currently using jquery-ui v. 1.11.4 and I can't quite figure out to make the appearances the same. I found what the [relevant section of css](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/dist/leaflet.draw.css#L223) from leaflet.draw, but when attempting to use the [tooltipclass property](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-tooltipClass) in the constructor as per below (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104148/4047679)), the two leaflet.draw class were added to the tooltip (and apparently overriden by existing jquery-ui class).

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({
  tooltipClass: ".leaflet-draw-tooltip .leaflet-draw-tooltip-single"
});
```

There seem to be two potential solutions:
 1. Create my own instance of a [leaflet.draw tooltip](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/1f49919df00467a234a9ed94c93bbfa9d804f6ec/src/Tooltip.js)
 2. Find a way to remove the conflicting CSS classes from the jquery-ui tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the `leaflet.draw.css` contained the following property:

```
visibility: hidden ;
```

So whenever I successfully applied the leaflet.draw CSS to the tooltip, it would vanish! (Kind of hard to debug).

So I created a class to override the `visibility` property and I added it to the tooltip declaration:

```
.j-leaflet-draw-tooltip{
    visibility: visible;
}

$( "#map" ).tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "leaflet-draw-tooltip leaflet-draw-tooltip-single
                   j-leaflet-draw-tooltip"
});
```